# How do you deal with complex data entry, creating related records within a record within a record?

Tags: forms, data-entry, relations

The database I am dealing with consists of objects that are related to each other in multiple (non-hierarchical) ways (documents, persons, places, events,...).

To create a new record the user has to choose from various select lists of other objects or create a new object record, which then might lead to the creation of new object records and so on...

In any case it might be a long way for the user to complete the creation of a record and she might have to add information later on.

See the screenshot for further understanding:

[image: relationship overkill]

[Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR2c7.png)

I'm not sure how to solve this problem:
A wizard might be to restrictive. What about subforms that slide out, when needed? A tree layout as navigator? Any suggestions?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: It looks as though the options presented to the user change depending on the choices they make - can you say more about the dependencies? It's important to set the user's expectations and give them feedback indicating where they are in the process. One way would be to break the process down into modules, telling the user what's happening, why and how long it will take. You might add some explanation as to whether your audience will be regular, occasional or once only users, as the needs will likely be different.

Comment: It looks like a 3D problem in a 2D space. Your goal is to reverse this concept. Make it a 2D problem in a 3D space. This eliminates certain options, like a wizard, but promotes some, like tabs. What i like most is applicable selections that pop up as i need it. Open or make available data based on where and what the user is doing on the record. Make it available as a tab or tree. And close all other windows. Shadow the user.

Comment: Very interesting topic, actually we are dealing with the same problem in one of our products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would describe this situation as:  **dynamic nested workflows**.

- *Dynamic* because you cannot tell ahead of time how deeply nested the workflow will be (user may not create any new objects, or may create multiple carriers and persons).
- *Nested* because the workflows for creating a carrier and then a person are nested within each other.

The dynamic nesting makes it difficult to lay out this kind of workflow in a wizard.

A common UX for nested workflows is **stacked modals**.  The reason for this is, the subworkflow(s) need to be completed before progress can be made on the parent workflow, so modal windows provide appropriate blocking behavior to ensure this happens.  Here are some stacked dialogs from a Microsoft Windows interface:

[image: stacked]

Stacked modals are not a great layout in general because they create visual clutter, but remember that in a [UX hierarchy](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/maslow-hierarchy-interface-design.png), functionality and usability wins over aesthetics, so in the case of nested workflows that usually drives the design choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with several "flexible" databases which were very powerful.  However, when it came to the user interface, the only way my users would be able to handle it was if they were first an expert at that sort of system, and none of my users ever were.

Instead of thinking that the system you described is a definition of the user flow, think that the system does not define a user flow at all, and that you get to build the front end to flow naturally for your users, even to the point of letting them skip some parts and fill them in later.  You still have to figure out a natural flow for your users and guide them through it, though, and it sort of sounds like that work hasn't been done yet.

If you do end up needing to provide an advanced way to look at the data, and you have too many options for tabs, the tree structure on the left idea like file folders and files is a comfortable way interact with things.  I always include "expand all" and "collapse all" buttons/links above my tree, but that is not strictly necessary.  Just be aware that few users will probably be able to understand and efficiently use this sort of interface.

Answer (score 0):

Creating and using data are usually different parts of a process, acknowledging this can simplify the system.

- Creating data is a simple operation on a low level, basically creating the underlying objects for the `Owner`, `Author` and `Place` roles. Perhaps the `Owner` and `Author` is played by a `Person` object, `Place` could be an `Address`.
- Using data is what the users does in any useful system, making connections between pieces of information. The `Information Carrier` seems to be such a connector. This is what the discussed part of the system should do.

By having an interface like the one you describe, basically a database GUI, it will become too low-level for most users, since they aren't familiar with the underlying data. As stated in your screenshot, when the user thinks about a `Document` he thinks about an `Owner` and an `Author`, not a `Person`, which may be the underlying object for both of them, containing pieces of information unknown to the user, but could be required by the data model.

Therefore, forcing/allowing a user to create a `Person` in the process of "Connecting information to a Document" is a mental model mismatch and could also be error-prone.

So my suggestion is to split the creation and usage:

1. Create the basic data objects, `Person`, `Address`, `Picture` etc. in another part of the system.
2. The document creation page can now be simplified to only making connections, hopefully everything on the same page to avoid the stack of modal dialogs looming in the screenshot. It should be possible now when it's only about selecting already existing data.
3. If new data needs to be created, do that in the other part of the system, return to the document creation and update the selection fields, manually or automatically.

If new data needs to be created for most new documents, there could be some information problem that needs to be solved, like importing pre-existing data, or even simplifying the data model so much that most relations will be reduced to a text field. The `Address` could be such a case. It's hard to know without a detailed data analysis.